# сохранение проверки значения для input

Tags: jquery, input

есть небольшой плагин для проверки ввода. для input например. проверку еще делаю небольшой регуляркой. и при неправильном вводе  присоединяю дивку по .after  . проблема в том что при вводе в другом инпуте after удаляется.  а нужно чтобы оставался

```
//сам плагин
```

```js
(function ($) {

      $.fn.textchanged = function() {
       $.event.special.textchange.triggerIfChanged($(this));
      }; 

      $.event.special.textchange = {
       
        setup: function (data, namespaces) {
            $(this).data('lastValue', this.contentEditable === 'true' ? $(this).html() : $(this).val());
            $(this).bind('keyup.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.handler);
           ///$(this).bind('keydown.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.handler);
            if ($(this).attr('type') == 'search') {
                $(this).bind('click.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.handler);
            }
            $(this).bind('cut.textchange paste.textchange input.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.delayedHandler);
          },
          
          teardown: function (namespaces) {
           $(this).unbind('.textchange');
          },
          
          handler: function (event) {
           $.event.special.textchange.triggerIfChanged($(this));
          },
          
          delayedHandler: function (event) {
           var element = $(this);
           setTimeout(function () {
            $.event.special.textchange.triggerIfChanged(element);
           }, 25);
          },
     
          triggerIfChanged: function (element) {
            var current = element[0].contentEditable === 'true' ? element.html() : element.val();
           if (current !== element.data('lastValue')) {
            element.trigger('textchange',  [element.data('lastValue')]);
            element.data('lastValue', current);
           }
          }
      };
 
 $.event.special.hastext = {
  
  setup: function (data, namespaces) {
   $(this).bind('textchange', $.event.special.hastext.handler);
  },
  
  teardown: function (namespaces) {
   $(this).unbind('textchange', $.event.special.hastext.handler);
  },
  
  handler: function (event, lastValue) {
   if ((lastValue === '') && lastValue !== $(this).val()) {
    $(this).trigger('hastext');
   }
  }
 };
 
 $.event.special.notext = {
  
  setup: function (data, namespaces) {
   $(this).bind('textchange', $.event.special.notext.handler);
  },
  
  teardown: function (namespaces) {
   $(this).unbind('textchange', $.event.special.notext.handler);
  },
  
  handler: function (event, lastValue) {
   if ($(this).val() === '' && $(this).val() !== lastValue) {
    $(this).trigger('notext');
   }
  }
 }; 

})(jQuery);


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     
    var err_fb =  $("<div class=\"c-validation\">Допустимы: только латиница, цифры и точка</div>"); 
    var err_fb1 =  $("<div class=\"c-validation\">Допустимы: 111 только латиница, цифры и точка</div>");

    var inputs = $('#edit-soc input'); 
    var regexp = /^[a-z0-9\.]+$/;

         inputs.on("textchange", $.event.special.textchange, function(event, previousText){
          //$(this).on("keyup blur focus change",  function(e){

            console.log($("input").val() + " - " + regexp.exec($("input").val())); 
           
            if (regexp.exec($("input").val()) === null ) {
                 $(this).after(err_fb ); 
            }
 
    });  
    
   inputs.each(function (i, input){
        if ($(input).val() === ''){ return; }
        var input = $(input);  
        console.log($(input).val() + " - " + regexp.exec($(input).val())); 
         
            if (regexp.exec($(input).val()) === null ) {
                   $(input).after(err_fb1 ); 
                    
                 }
 
     });          
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/u/2242/s" method="post" id="form-soc" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="hideSubmitButton-processed">
 
<fieldset class="collapsible form-wrapper collapse-processed" id="edit-soc">
<div class="main-fld"> 
         
<input placeholder="Имя" type="text" id="edit-fb-profile" name="fb_profile" value="222kkk" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
<input placeholder="Им" type="text" id="edit-fb-page" name="fb_page" value="123hhh" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text"> 
 
</div></fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-ktPa_acH6rkjsM0_Bmr93rKs0I9a22LvNLUJ8jTaBmM">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="w8ZV3UUf5HiwZISwyK8EsO-k0REHqlNiSUY_y_57AFs">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="uss_form_soc">


<input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Сохранить" class="form-submit"></form>
```

Не понимаю, как сделать увы. опыта с jquery практически нет. но стараюсь. Заранее извините за неправильности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам предлагаю поставить блоки ошибок прямо в нужное место, и скрыть их через CSS. Так будет проще, да и html-код не надо будет в JS хранить.

Затем когда нужно будет показать ошибку - просто покажите блок:

```
if (regexp.exec($(this).val()) === null ) {
    $(this).next('.c-validation').show();
}else{
    $(this).next('.c-validation').hide();
}
```

> Но: "Допустимы: только латиница, цифры и точка" - это одно состояние.
>   А я хочу как минимум два три.

Вот такой вариант:

Можно использовать [data-атрибуты](https://api.jquery.com/data/). В них можно хранить любую информацию, например, тип проверки поля:

```
<input ... data-type="all" placeholder="Здесь можно: латиница, цифры и точку">
<input ... data-type="lat" placeholder="Здесь можно: только латиница">
```

Затем в скрипте получить это значение и выбрать регулярку относительно него:

```
if ($(this).data('type') == "all") {
      var regexp = /^[a-z0-9\.]+$/;
}else{
      var regexp = /^[a-z]+$/;
}
```

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.textchanged = function() {
    $.event.special.textchange.triggerIfChanged($(this));
  };

  $.event.special.textchange = {

    setup: function(data, namespaces) {
      $(this).data('lastValue', this.contentEditable === 'true' ? $(this).html() : $(this).val());
      $(this).bind('keyup.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.handler);
      ///$(this).bind('keydown.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.handler);
      if ($(this).attr('type') == 'search') {
        $(this).bind('click.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.handler);
      }
      $(this).bind('cut.textchange paste.textchange input.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.delayedHandler);
    },

    teardown: function(namespaces) {
      $(this).unbind('.textchange');
    },

    handler: function(event) {
      $.event.special.textchange.triggerIfChanged($(this));
    },

    delayedHandler: function(event) {
      var element = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $.event.special.textchange.triggerIfChanged(element);
      }, 25);
    },

    triggerIfChanged: function(element) {
      var current = element[0].contentEditable === 'true' ? element.html() : element.val();
      if (current !== element.data('lastValue')) {
        element.trigger('textchange', [element.data('lastValue')]);
        element.data('lastValue', current);
      }
    }
  };

  $.event.special.hastext = {

    setup: function(data, namespaces) {
      $(this).bind('textchange', $.event.special.hastext.handler);
    },

    teardown: function(namespaces) {
      $(this).unbind('textchange', $.event.special.hastext.handler);
    },

    handler: function(event, lastValue) {
      if ((lastValue === '') && lastValue !== $(this).val()) {
        $(this).trigger('hastext');
      }
    }
  };

  $.event.special.notext = {

    setup: function(data, namespaces) {
      $(this).bind('textchange', $.event.special.notext.handler);
    },

    teardown: function(namespaces) {
      $(this).unbind('textchange', $.event.special.notext.handler);
    },

    handler: function(event, lastValue) {
      if ($(this).val() === '' && $(this).val() !== lastValue) {
        $(this).trigger('notext');
      }
    }
  };

})(jQuery);


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {



  var inputs = $('#edit-soc input');


  inputs.on("textchange", $.event.special.textchange, function(event, previousText) {

    if ($(this).data('type') == "all") {
      var regexp = /^[a-z0-9\.]+$/;
    }else if ($(this).data('type') == "numbers") {
      var regexp = /^[0-9\.]+$/;
    }else{
      var regexp = /^[a-z]+$/;
    }

    if (regexp.exec($(this).val()) === null) {
      $(this).next('.c-validation').show();
    } else {
      $(this).next('.c-validation').hide();
    }

  });



});
```

```css
.c-validation {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/u/2242/s" method="post" id="form-soc" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="hideSubmitButton-processed">

  <fieldset class="collapsible form-wrapper collapse-processed" id="edit-soc">
    <div class="main-fld">

      <input type="text" id="edit-fb-profile" name="fb_profile" value="" data-type="numbers" placeholder="Здесь можно только цифры и точку" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
      <div class="c-validation">Допустимы: только цифры и точка</div>

      <input  type="text" id="edit-fb-page" name="fb_page" value="" size="60" data-type="all" placeholder="Здесь можно: латиница, цифры и точку" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
      <div class="c-validation">Допустимы: только латиница, цифры и точка</div>

      <input  type="text" id="edit-fb-page" name="fb_page" value="" size="60" data-type="lat" placeholder="Здесь можно только латиница и все" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
      <div class="c-validation">Допустимы: только латиница</div>


    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-ktPa_acH6rkjsM0_Bmr93rKs0I9a22LvNLUJ8jTaBmM">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="w8ZV3UUf5HiwZISwyK8EsO-k0REHqlNiSUY_y_57AFs">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="uss_form_soc">


  <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Сохранить" class="form-submit"></form>
```

PS. кстати, я исправил `$("input").val()` на `this`, т.к. мне кажется, у вас ошибка в этом месте.

Comment: Доброй  ночи. Насчёт скрытия через css  специально не делал. в html  будет 8 дивок и разный текст. И то что Вы удалили .each() , да - не работает он. Только при первом открытии страницы делает обход инпутов и всё.  И как сделать чтобы, дивка оставалась если в инпуте остаётся неверно ввёдённое значение, я не знаю. Не получается увы

Comment: @Александр вот, пожалуйста, мое решение прекрасно масштабируется. Не понимаю, чем может не нравится такой вариант

Comment: Доброе утро, спасибо что ответили. Как бы не был уверен, что кто-то ответит вообще. Насчёт решения. Да css меняется и состояние визуальное сохраняется. как и нужно. Но: "Допустимы: только латиница, цифры и точка" - это одно состояние. А я хочу как минимум два три. after я не знаю почему не пашет как у Вас. Не знаю всех тонкостей в js увы. По идее css меняется, after тоже дом элемент создаёт. Или тут какая то хитрость есть при манипулировании элементами?

Comment: Я наверное не понимаю как работает after и append - может из-за этого и проблемы у меня

Comment: @Александр `after` у вас в скипте перемещают элемент от одного элемента к другому. Допустим вы сделаете копию объекта, тогда столкнетесь с другой проблемой, у вас элементы будут дублироваться при каждом нажатии, надо будет как-то проверять не был ли уже добавлен элемент. Так-что лучше возьмите на вооружение мой способ.

Comment: хорошо а если только дивки будут созданы а манипулировать .text()  а сам текст в виде массива в js ?  Так сработает как у Вас или нет?

Comment: @Александр исправил ответ. Впронципе, так как вы говорите тоже должно работать, но тут проблема связать массив и html-верстку. Все, конечно, решается, но я предлагаю простой и масштабируемый способ

Comment: .data  - спасибо.  сейчас поэкспериментирую с этим методом для атрибута. не знал про него. а Вы про .clone() как я понимаю? и проверка $("div").is(".lBlock") . спасибо. буду сейчас экспериментировать. Надо повышать знания

Comment: Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http:///ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: +15 как появится у меня. сразу плюсану.